# How to get the day name from a selected date in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

Get the day name (example: Monday, Tuesday, ..... ) from a selected date from `datepicker`

```
 let day = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: show your tried cdoe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the weekday do the following:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
var weekday: String = ""
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "cccc"
weekday = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Read more about the different formats here:
http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Comment: not working for me... i want as for date 26/03/2019 as tuesday

Comment: what result do you get?

Comment: getting as Monday but i want as monday

Comment: just do weekday.lowercased() if you want to have the letter lowercased

Comment: yes get, one more thing if i change the date the day will not changing

Comment: If you dont show your code i cant help you. But all your questions are probably answered somewhere on stackoverflow

Comment: func daySelect() {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        let vc = CustomDatePickerAlert()
       vc.view.frame = CGRect(origin: self.view.center, size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 50, height: vc.view.frame.height))
        vc.treatDelegate = self
        
       self.present(vc, animated: true)
        let wday = dateFormatter.string(from: vc.treatmtDatePicker.date)
       // onClickDate.setTitle(date, for: .normal)
        print(wday + "")
        day = wday

Comment: also a function for select date in dd/mm/yyyy format all two functions call in a button click

Answer (score 4):

Add this extension in below any file in the project. (better make an extension file and add there.)

```
extension Date {
    func dayNameOfWeek() -> String? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let dayName = date.dayNameOfWeek()
```